# How to flip a phylogeny horizontally?

Tags: r, rotation, flip, phylogeny

I have a phylogeny, like this:

```
library(phytools)
set.seed(30)

phylogeny <- pbtree(n = 26)
phylogeny$tip.label <- LETTERS
plotTree(phylogeny, type = "fan", lwd = .5)
```

This code gave me the following phylogeny:

[image]

**Note that the tips went counterclockwise**, I need to flip the phylogeny horizontally, **making the tips follow clockwise!**

I've tried to use `rotateNodes(phylogeny, "all")` but didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`rotateNodes` works if used before plotting.

```
plotTree(rotateNodes(phylogeny, nodes = "all"), type = "fan", lwd = .5)
```

[image]